# Форма свернута в трей, события мыши и клавиатуры

Tags: c#, winforms

Приложение WindowsForms свернуто в трей. Возможно ли отследить нажатие любой клавиши и движение курсора мыши?

Comment: А основная Ваша задача в чем состоит?

Comment: Программа через определенные временные интервалы показывает и опять сворачивает форму

Comment: При создании проекта WinForm зайдите в класс Programm и там будут выполняться действия именно программы, и от туда можно отследить, НО не забывайте про то что пока открыта формачка в основном потоке код не выполняеться дальше.

Comment: Есть класс Program, но как можно в нем обработать например событие нажатие любой клавиши?